# how to overcome the recursive error in trigger?

Tags: trigger

I have written the trigger on service object.but i got error,i know updating the record on same object.how to overcome this type of error ?

my error is Like::

> Error:Apex trigger updateaccounting caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: updateaccounting: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0G4E000000BTRKUA4; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a0G4E000000BTRK) is currently in trigger updateaccounting, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []: Trigger.updateaccounting: line 48, column 1

```
    trigger updateaccounting on Service__c (before insert,before update) {

    string custclass;
    string prodclass;
    string acccustclass;
    string accprodclass;
    string strServiceId;


    List<Service__c>lstservices = new List<Service__c>();
    List<Service__c> lstservicesUpdate = new List<Service__c>();
    List<Accounting__c> lstaccounting = new List<Accounting__c>();
    List<Service__c>lstservices1 = new List<Service__c>();
    lstservices1 = [select Car_set__r.Order__r.Account.Customer_VAT_type__c,CB_Services_Repository__r.Rfleet_Product_classification__c from Service__c where id IN :Trigger.new];

    system.debug('lstservices1 >>>>>>>>>'+lstservices1);
    for(Service__c service : lstservices1 ){
        strServiceId=service.id;
        custclass = service.Car_set__r.Order__r.Account.Customer_VAT_type__c;
        prodclass =service.CB_Services_Repository__r.Rfleet_Product_classification__c;
        system.debug('product classification values>>>>>'+prodclass+custclass );

        lstaccounting = [select Rfleet_Customer_Tax__c,Rfleet_Product_Tax__c from Accounting__c];


        for(Accounting__c accounting : lstaccounting ){

            system.debug('Accounting values>>>'+accounting);
            acccustclass = accounting.Rfleet_Customer_Tax__c;
            system.debug('accountcustomerclassfication values>>>>'+acccustclass);
            accprodclass = accounting.Rfleet_Product_Tax__c ;
            system.debug('accountproductclassfication values>>>'+accprodclass);

            if(acccustclass == custclass && accprodclass == prodclass){

                system.debug('>>>>>>>>>inside if>>');
                service.Rfleet_Accounting__c =accounting.id;
                service.id=strServiceId;

                system.debug('>>>>>>>>>'+service.Rfleet_Accounting__c);
                system.debug('>>>>>>>>>'+accounting .id);
                lstservicesUpdate.add(service);

            }
        }

    }
    update lstservicesUpdate;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 
>>>>SOQL query inside for loop<<<<
Also as @mr. frodo said , no need for DML in before triggers?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to update the `Service__c` list in the before update itself.That is not required.

> You cannot recursively update or delete the same object from an Apex
>   trigger. This error often occurs when: A trigger performs a DML
>   operation that ends up updating a record that is already being updated
>   by another trigger. It must not cause a DML event to occur on a record
>   already involved in the same DML event. For example, it is okay to
>   update the record during an insert, and it is okay to delete during an
>   update, but you cannot update inside an update (this includes the
>   upsert or convert command).
>
> This error occurs with both direct and indirect operations. The
>   following is an example of an indirect operation:
>
> 1. A request is submitted to update Object A.
> 2. A before update trigger on object A creates an object B.
> 3. Object A is updated.
> 4. An after insert trigger on object B queries object A and updates it. This is an indirect update of object A because of the
>      before trigger of object A, so an error is generated.

Comment: Hi,Mr.Frodo.thanks for your reply.how to rectify that error .please suggest me.where i have to change my code.

Comment: You just have to use the Trigger.newlist of Service__c.Make whatever changes you want to do in that and remove the DML(Update) statement.It will automatically update or insert it with the changes you want.